# Reset multiple shape key values back to 0?

Tags: shape-keys

If I have a bunch of shapekeys active at varying values, is there a faster way to reset every shape key's value back to 0 rather than do it one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just click on the X button near the value field.

2.7:

[image]

and 2.8:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I missed this, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what's worse. The fact that I have never even noticed this button's functionality before, or that its icon and position always made me think it would delete the selected shapekey.... Definitely not the best UX there!

Answer (score 2):

You can run this line in the Python console to reset all shape key values of the **active object** to 0.0:

```
[setattr(x, 'value', 0) for x in bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks]
```

Basically, all shape keys of an object are accessible via the `myObject.data.shape_keys.key_blocks` list. From there you can manipulate all of the properties. The one-liner above is just an abbreviated way of writing the code below in the Script Editor of Blender and executing it:

```
import bpy

for skey in bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    skey.value = 0.0
```